# How can I locate the Outlook 2013 folder creation date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a way to locate the creation date of a 2013 Outlook folder? As noted in the graphic, I want to know the creation date and if possible who created the folder.
[Outlook 2013 Folder Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXR5W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can't see who created the folder. But you can see the creation date, it's PR_CREATION_TIME MAPI property. To get the value of this property, you can use either VBA or one of the free tools. For example, Microsoft's [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [Universal Folder Report](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookReportFoldersUniversal) made by my company (add, say "Created" to the left text box and {FIELD#CreationTime} macro to the right text box).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Office 365 (or Exchange) you can connect with [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) and use the Get-MailboxFolderStatistics cmdlet. This will get you the create date. See Powershell code below:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication  Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Get-MailboxFolder -identity user@user.com
```